# Find number of battery charge cycles Swift

Tags: swift, battery

i want to build an app that tells the user the environmental impact of different products, and naturally i want to include the phone itself in this. to do this i want to know how much electricity my phone has used up over its lifetime to calculate the electrical consumption.

as such, im trying to work out how many times my battery has been charged (how many cycles) in swift. ive looked into the documentation for `UIDevice.BatteryState` but it doesnt seem to give me this info? i also found some info pointing me at `IOKit` but not much further, the apple doc that ive found said that its unsupported?

theres an app called [CoconutFlavour](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery) that does this, and i can find the maximum capacity in the menus but i need to find it using Swift.

[image: e cycles]

how do i find the number of cycles my battery has run through in Swift? which class am i looking for? please help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Apple keeps the battery information of the phone in log-power-date.session File and this file contains phone information written in XML. It writes the information you want in `<key>.com.apple.ioreport.BatterCycleCount </key> section.`
This file is located in the analysis and data section of the phone's privacy section. But I don't know how you can get it with an app.

Comment: ok, thank you. would i be able to access it through some other means then that you know of?

Comment: I really do not know. Maybe if you can get those numbers in the part where it shows the charge information, you can calculate how many times it cycles from 0 to 100. But I don't know how you get these numbers.but good idea i use it if you can make such an app :)